# Vue.js - Output array selection on click to console

Tags: html, vue.js

I have a system where I can search names/ages. I want to log whatever array option I click to the console, for example, click "Donnie - 20", console logs "Donnie". I tried my best with the exclude method but I cannot seem to get it to work

Vue.js

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    keyword: '',
    friends: [
      {
      name: "Donnie",
      age: "20"
    },
    {
        name: "Joanne",
        age:"19",
     },
      {
      name: "David",
      age: "26"
    },
      {
      name: "Peter",
      age: "23"
    },
      {
      name: "John",
      age: "29"
    },
      {
      name: "Jason",
      age: "19"
    },
     ],
  },
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.friends.filter((friend) => {
        return friend.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword) + friend.age.includes(this.keyword) + friend.name.includes(this.keyword);
      });

      }
    },

  methods:{
      exclude(filteredList, friends) {
      console.log(this.age);
    },
  }

  })
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="search-wrapper">
        <input type="text" v-model="keyword" placeholder="Search.."/>
    <label>Search Title:</label>
      </div>
    <div v-for="friend in filteredList" class="card" @click="exclude()">
      {{friend.name}} - {{friend.age}}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've added 2 arguments to your method but you aren't passing anything to it.

Calling this.age in the method is looking for data.age which is undefined. What you want to do is change your HTML portion to:

```
<div v-for="friend in filteredList" class="card" @click="exclude(friend)">
```

Then change your method to be:

```
exclude(friend) {
  console.log(`${friend.name} - ${friend.age}`);
},
```

Or whatever you'd like your console string to look like.

Comment: Okay that works by using "console.log(friend.age)" now, how would I target every part of the array apart from the one I clicked?

Comment: @DonnieBerry What do you mean by target every part of the array? Do you want to log every person except the one you clicked?

Comment: Yes, For example, if I click "Donnie", it would log everybody APART from Donnie. My example I am going for is when I click an array (for e.g, Donnie), it will hide the rest of the array, and when I click "Donnie" againn, the rest of the array will show again.